# Laravel search form using database

Tags: forms, laravel

I have a search form with three fields: Department, Role and Location which I'm calling Contacts search and it is to be on multiple pages.

Here is a picture:

[image]

To this extent, I made it a Blade include so I could just re-use it wherever I need it.

All of the values for these fields are available to me in the Users table as I could do the following:

`SELECT DISTINCT department, role, location FROM users`

This would give me all of the unique roles, departments and locations.

However, for me to populate this form via the database would I have to pass the data to the parent view every time?

For instance, I was thinking something like this.

**In Controller**

`$formFields = User::distinct()->get(['department', 'role', 'location']);`

**In view**

```
@foreach(formFields as $field)
    $field->department
    ...
    ...
@endforeach
```

The only issue is, surely I would have to send this data to every view that uses the form?

Alternatively, do I just make a SearchController that uses the User model to feed into it?

Is it possible to feed data to a partial view in this way?

Update

View composers do seem to be the way to go, however I don't feel this is valid:

```
view()->composer('layouts.quick-search', function($view) {
            $view->with('departments', \App\User::distinct()->get(['department']),
                        'locations', \App\User::distinct()->get(['location']),
                        'roles', \App\User::distinct()->get(['role']));
        });
```

As it doesn't seem to like multiple variables.

I also tried the following:

```
<select class="form-control transparant" id="department" name="department">
    @foreach($departments as $department)

        <option value="{{ $department }}">{{ $department }}</option>

    @endforeach

</select>
```

But this filled the select box with:

`{"department":"Digital","profile":null}`

This is clearly an array, but does this mean I'll have to JSON decode this?

Comment: I would open a `php` script at the top of the blade page and get the data from there instead from the controller itself. That way, everytime you call your partial view it will render and load its own data

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you could do something like this:

In view

```
@php $formFields = \App\User::distinct()->get(['department', 'role', 'location']); @endphp
@foreach(formFields as $field)
    $field->department
    ...
    ...
@endforeach
```

Another way to do this would be creating a group of all those views that use the partial view. Apply a middleware to that group where you assign the data to the request or share the data to the views using `View::share()`

Answer (score 0):

[View composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) are perfect for this.

You create a separate view for the form, something like `search` and put this in a service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\User;
// ...
publlic function boot()
{
    View::composer('search', function ($view) {
        $view->with([
            'formFields' => User::distinct()->get(['department', 'role', 'location']);
        ]);
    });
}
```

Now every time the `search` view will be used, this query will be executed and the results will be passed to the view.